# What is the $w^{*}$-closure of the finite rank operators in $B(H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I know that the norm closure of the finite rank operators on a Hilbert space is the compact operators $K(H)$. I've been trying to determine what is the $w^{*}$-closure but I am not getting any good results. I am thinking it might be the whole $B(H)$. Is this closure known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the whole of $B(H)$. This simply follows from [Goldstine's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem) and the dualities between $K(H)$, $K(H)^*$ and $B(H)$ (try to write down the corresponding duality brackets yourself).

You may replace here $H$ with any [reflexive Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space) that has the [bounded approximation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property).